# For $X$ infinite dimensional, the map $H_k(X^n)\to H_k(X)$ induced by the inclusion $X^n\to X$ is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Lemma 2.34. in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, the infinite case of $(c)$, he wants to show the following:

For $X$ infinite dimensional, the map $H_k(X^n)\to H_k(X)$ induced by the inclusion $X^n\to X$ is an isomorphism for $k < n$ and surjective for $k = n$.

I can understand everything up to the last paragraph of this approach:

> So a $k$-cycle in $X$ is a cycle in some $X^m$, and then **by the
> finite-dimensional case of (c), the cycle is homologous to a cycle in
> $X^n$ if $n\geq k$, so $H_k(X^n)\to H_k(X)$ is surjective.** Similarly for injectivity,
> if a $k$-cycle in $X^n$ bounds a chain in $X$, this chain lies in some $X^m$
> with $m \geq n$, so by the finite-dimensional case the cycle bounds a chain
> in $X^n$ if $n > k$.

Specifically, I cannot understand:

1. How the first bold statement is obtained from the finite dimensional case. I'm unable to formalize this. Is he perhaps using $(c)$ with $H_k(X^n)\cong H_k(X^m)$? If so, then why does it not bother us that it might be the case that $n>m$?
2. I cannot understand the injectivity - in particular, what is the meaning of a $k$-cycle bounding a chain in $X$?

I tried seeing this using the infinite dimensional sphere, which can be constructed as a CW complex, so if there's any intuition to be gained through that - it would be great.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n$.

The previous sentence in Hatcher notes that any singular chain in $X$ lies in a finite subcomplex. In particular, if $\sigma$ is a $k$-cycle in $X$, then its image lies in a finite subcomplex $Y$. Since $Y$ is finite, it happens to be a subcomplex of $X^m$ for some $m$, and we may assume that $m \geq n$. (If we know that $Y$ is contained in $X^m$, then it's also in $X^q$ for all $q \geq m$, so we can increase $m$ as needed.)

But I think we don't need to refer to $X^m$, so forget about it. Apply the finite-dimensional case to the $k$-cycle $\sigma$ in $Y \subset X$: if $n \geq k$, then it is homologous to a $k$-cycle in $Y^n \subset X^n$. Therefore the inclusion $X^n \to X$ induces a surjection on $H_k$.

For question 2, saying that a $k$-cycle bounds a chain in $X$ means that it is in the image of the boundary map $C_{k+1}(X) \to C_k(X)$, where $C_k(-)$ denotes the singular $k$-chains.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand your first paragraph -- Hatcher is indeed using (c) with $H_k(X^n)\to H_k(X)$ and we don't mind that $n>m$ because we can increase as $m$ as needed. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right.